# on linux, how do I list only mounted removable media / device?

Tags: linux, bash, redhat, mount, sles

I know we can list all mounted devices using the `mount` command. or even the `df` command.

But how can we know if the listed device is removable or not, such as USB, CMROM, External Hardisk, etc?

For this question, we can start with how to do it on SUSE or RedHat.

Thanks!

Comment: On SUSE if you plugged the media in (you being your user), then it will be listed under `/run/media/you/`. `df -h | grep media` should find all generally.

Comment: so generally `grep media` refers to only removable media / devices, am I right? Sorry but by any chance that this is stated in documentation or is it a publicly known secret? :P

Comment: It would either be mentioned in `man df` (or possibly in the info page), but otherwise it's likely up to the kernel on what information it passes to `df`. Publicly known secret? No, not really, but may take a read of the kernel docs or the `df` source code. (that's publicly known, but not a secret `:)`

Comment: The user documentation for your version of Linux will probably explain about the `media` directory.  (For example, https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/ch-filesystem, section 2.1.1.6).The secret to finding Linux secrets is to read the documentation :-)

Comment: found this:
```2.1.1.6. The /media/ Directory
The /media/ directory contains subdirectories used as mount points for removable media, such as USB storage media, DVDs, and CD-ROMs.```

Thanks!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you may want to add the answer so that I can mark it as acceptable. basically we can use `mount`, `df`, or `lsblk` then `grep -E '\s/media/` to filter just the removable device

Comment: I think I found a reasonable solution for you. It still doesn't answer how the information gets to `df`, but it does show its locaiton in sysfs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking about this a bit more, the way to determine if a drive is removable is to check whether the contents of:

```
/sys/block/sdX/removable
```

Is set to `0` - non-removable or `1` - removable. You can get the list of mounted drives (presuming the form `/dev/sdX` where `X` is `a`, `b`, `c`, etc..) and then loop over the devices checking the contents of the `removable` file.

For `bash` using *Process-Substitution* to feed a `while` loop to loop over the device names removing the trailing partition digits and only taking unique devices you could do:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while read -r name; do
  if [ "$(<${name/dev/sys\/block}/removable)" -eq "1" ]; then 
    echo "$name - removable"
  else
    echo "$name - non-removable"
  fi
done < <(awk '/^\/dev\/sd/ {sub(/[0-9]+$/,"",$1); print $1}' /proc/mounts | uniq)
```

Which will list all devices and whether they are removable. For example, running the script with a flash drive inserted (`/dev/sdc`) and my normal hard drive (`/dev/sdb`), you would receive:

```
$ bash list-removable.sh
/dev/sdb - non-removable
/dev/sdc - removable
```

There are probably many other ways to do it.

Comment: let me test this out

Comment: Let me know if you have issues, and I'll tweak it. The process substitution is bash-only as is the parameter expansion with substring replacement. But other than those two items (which you can work around with a pipe and a couple parameter expansions with substring removal for POSIX), the rest is POSIX.

Comment: should we not limit to `/dev\/sd/`? I can see there's a sr0 in my devices. note that i'm testing on SLES 15 on virtualbox with mounted cdrom.

Comment: You can add the `srN` if you also want to find optical drives.  You could change `awk '/^\/dev\/s/ ...` to include all `/dev/s...` drives.

Comment: just checking, what other possible values other than `sd` and `sr`? Just want to understand why not just list all in `/dev/`?

Comment: That's a good question, the `sd` is generally for mass storage devices and `sr` are generally for removable optical devices CD/DVD, etc.. A quick check of 4 Linux boxes shows those are the only types registered I have, but that would need more research for a definite answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
for dev in /dev/disk/by-id/usb*; do mount | grep $(readlink -f ${dev}); done
```

This first runs mount to list devices that are mounted. It then looks at /dev/disk/by-id/ which will have a udev link to the device, using the manufacture id of the device. This link will resolve to the /dev/device that it corresponds to. It greps the output of mount for these devices and will display them on the screen along with their current mount points and fs options.

**Edit to include checking against mount*

Comment: `lsusb` will do that too, without the loop `:)`, but other than the fact that `lsusb` was run, knowing the manufacturer, doesn't specifically provide that it is "removable" per se.

Comment: `lsusb` will only list all usb devices, and will not share their mount points or /dev/ device name.
knowing the manufacture doesn't help with knowing what is removable. However, if it is usb it will start with `usb`-manufacture-serialnumber so if you search for stuff starting with usb(or you could do mmc etc) you will get only removeable drives. 
To know which are mounted, you can reference the `mount` or `df` command against the above list.

Comment: Yes, correct, the `lsusb` comment was simply in reference to "*using the manufacture id*" and wasn't intended to be a one-stop solution. You can likely combine as you indicate, but still even with the manufacturer ID, you still need to confirm what the device is and that it's removable unless you just want to rely on the fact it is usb.

Comment: I think its a pretttty safe assumption that if its a disk, and usb, its removeable.

Comment: Yes, it is safe that it is plugged in via usb, but whether it is a thunb drive or a hard disk enclosure, etc.. is still up in the air. But I'm in no way saying it won't be removable or your approach is a bad one, all add pieces of information you can draw from.

Comment: yeah, there's another question asking about USB:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34973772/how-to-find-all-usb-devices-connected-in-linux-ubuntu